# C# while loops and semi colons

Tags: c#

I am running a code and if I write it like this:

```
int num = 0;
while (num++ < 6) ;
{
Console.WriteLine(num);         
}
```

I get an output of 7

but if it's written like this

```
int num = 0;
while (num++ < 6)
{
Console.WriteLine(num);         
}
```

I get an output of 1,2,3,4,5,6

I am really confused on why the outputs are so different just by adding an extra semicolon in.
I get why it is 7 for the top code, but why doesn't it show a loop of all of the answers?

Really appreciate it if someone could explain :)
Thanks

Comment: The top one is the same as `while (num++ < 6) { } { Console.WriteLine(num); }` which is the same as `while (num++ < 6) { } Console.WriteLine(num)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semicolon means that the whole while loop is that line - it means the {} block afterwards isn't part of the loop - but rather what happens next.

So this:

```
int num = 0;
while (num++ < 6) ;
{
Console.WriteLine(num);         
}
```

is the same as writing:

```
int num = 0;
while (num++ < 6) 
{
}
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

See the difference?

Answer (score 2):

When you debug the code, you would see :

```
    int num = 0;
while (num++ < 6) ;  //It checks until num>6 (6 times)                            
{                    //without running the code inside the Curly Brackets
Console.WriteLine(num);         // Then it runs just once this line
}
```

and that's because of the semicolon

For the second option

```
int num = 0;
while (num++ < 6)   // it checks the condition every time
{
Console.WriteLine(num);     // it runs this line of code 6 times    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when doing some course-work at uni and have never forgot this. Basically you are terminating the while loop with the semi-colon without running the code inside. The curly brackets are then removed by the compiler and you end up with this:

```
int num = 0;
while (num++ < 6) {}
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

The problem is this is horrendous to find and can cause major bugs if this code goes into production. TBH I'm not sure why compilers allow this or what it would be useful for!

Answer (score 1):

```
int num = 0;                      // num is 0
while (num++ < 6) ;               // the ; makes this "function" repeat until 6 is reached
{                                 // since function above has ; this { does nothing
    Console.WriteLine(num);       // prints where num stopped at, which is 6  
}                                 // since function above has ; this } does nothing

=====================================================================================

/* This function is the same as... */
int num = 0;
while (num++ < 6)
{
    DoNothing();
}

Console.WriteLine(num);
```

```
int num = 0;                      // num is 0
while (num++ < 6)                 // no ; makes this "function" do num++ then continue
{                                 // { start of the instructions
    Console.WriteLine(num);       // prints where num stopped at, first round is 1
}                                 // end of the instructions
                                  // will go back to while loop until num reaches 6
```